# .NET Storing "Checked" items into the database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Wondering if someone could assist with the best way to handle storing "checked" items in a MSSQL database. 
On my form, i have a list of fields (name, address ect) and then a listbox the user can check for e.g. favourite colors.

In my database I would have a table for user details (tbl_userdetails - [UserID, Address...]) and a table for colors (tbl_colors, [ColorID, ColorName, ColorCode]). I would also need a table for user colors (tbl_userColors - [userID, ColorID])Theses would be linked via a "userID"

Normally, to save the user details, I have a sql string "UPDATE tbl_userdetails SET... WHERE userID = @userID". What is the best way to save the changed checked items into the next table?

My thoughts are:

1. Delete all the colors for UserID in the tbl_userColors and then loop the checked items into a "INSERT" statment.
2. Loop though each item that exists in the list create a datatable and then "merge" the data (on match, insert. on not matched delete)

Any other thoughts? What is the best way to build the INSERT statment?

Cheers

Comment: How many possible colors are allowed?

Comment: @TnTinMn - This could be any number. It's more of an example of the problem. Can be applied to categories or users ect

Answer (score 0):

The DELETE and INSERT strategy works well as long as nothing is tied to those records.  If you ever have any tables that reference `tbl_userColors` on the "one" side of the relationship, then you will have headaches.

The MERGE strategy is decent, usually.  One possibly unfortunate consequence would be that a MISSING record is the same as a FALSE record.  For instance, you Have your list of colors, `{red, green, blue}`, and your users are making their selections.  Six months later you get crazy and add `orange`.  Now you have no idea who didn't select orange vs. those that simply weren't presented with orange as an option.

A third option is to place an `Enabled BIT` field on the `tbl_userColors` table.  This allows you to determine if a user was presented with a color option and they declined it vs. if the user never saw a particular color option.

Speaking of Enabled BITs.  Your `tbl_colors` table should really have an Enabled BIT as well - or some other mechanism of removing a color from the UI without removing its database record.  You realize at some point you no longer want to offer `blue` to your users, but you also don't want to loose the historical data.

And a small aside:  Your tables names are horrific.  You should really consider dropping the Hungarian notation.  I'm a big fan of camel-case table names:  `Users`, `Colors`, and `UserColors`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. (Table names are examples only, i am using the camel-case normally). There is nothing else looking at the UserColors table, just want to be able to use the information, the delete/inser is what i normally use in this case. But want to see what is best. I don't need to know about the extra colors. I only normally store the colors that are "checked" in the database, but display the whole list in my control.

Answer (score -1):

Simple really. When an item is checked it returns a boolean. Whenever you get ready to save to the database you just want to loop through the colors and if it is checked (AKA is check is true) then you add it to a list that you can later loop through to save all of the values.